# How to adjust pure flexbox masonry grid in Chrome, which already works in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a flexbox masonry grid that works perfectly fine in firefox, including automatic resizing etc. But in Chrome it doesn't work, check the images.

This is the SCSS code that I use

```css
.jinya-vertical-art-gallery {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% + 1rem);
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery__page-title {
  font-family: $jinya-page-title-font-family;
  font-size: $jinya-page-title-font-size;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork {
  height: 15rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 27rem;
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 27rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery__caption {
  display: none;
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery-caption__title {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  display: block;
  font-size: $jinya-vertical-art-gallery-caption-font-size;
  font-weight: $jinya-vertical-art-gallery-caption-font-weight;
  font-family: $heading-font-family;
}
```

And this is the rendered HTML:

```html
<div class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery">
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/320" alt="Aokigahara"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/270/350" alt="Zack"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/230/320" alt="Final touch"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/280" alt="autumn"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/410/620" alt="Treehouse"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/190/390" alt="Treehouse Process"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/240/250" alt="Gentle"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/210/380" alt="Lolita"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/100/320" alt="Step by Step 2"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/400/370" alt="Spring"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/290/310" alt="Sailor Goths"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/310/300" alt="Rest"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/120/360" alt="Guardian Demon"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/180/280" alt="Link"> </figure>
</div>
```

This is how it looks in firefox:

[image]

This is how it looks in Chrome:

[image]

Note, the images need to be blurred because of copyright reasons, but the grid should be visible.

Comment: I've run your code on FF and Chrome (74.0.3729.131). The masonry effect with auto resizing seems to be working fine on both browsers here. https://jsfiddle.net/86owmgsx/

Comment: @Michael_B I checked the fiddle, if you resize the result canvas it produces gaps at the end but still a masonry grid. I need to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you overdid the layout with nesting flex layouts - each artwork figure does not need to be a flex container. Removing that constraint will make each artwork figure take the size of the children - in that case it would be the artwork. A sample solution can be found below:

```css
.jinya-vertical-art-gallery {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% + 1rem);
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery__page-title {
  font-family: $jinya-page-title-font-family;
  font-size: $jinya-page-title-font-size;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 27rem;
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image {
  height: 15rem;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 27rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery__caption {
  display: none;
}

.jinya-vertical-art-gallery-caption__title {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  display: block;
  font-size: $jinya-vertical-art-gallery-caption-font-size;
  font-weight: $jinya-vertical-art-gallery-caption-font-weight;
  font-family: $heading-font-family;
}
```

```html
<div class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery">
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/320" alt="Aokigahara"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/270/350" alt="Zack"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/230/320" alt="Final touch"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/300/280" alt="autumn"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/410/620" alt="Treehouse"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/190/390" alt="Treehouse Process"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/240/250" alt="Gentle"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/210/380" alt="Lolita"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/100/320" alt="Step by Step 2"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/400/370" alt="Spring"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/290/310" alt="Sailor Goths"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/310/300" alt="Rest"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/120/360" alt="Guardian Demon"> </figure>
<figure class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery__artwork"> <img class="jinya-vertical-art-gallery-artwork__image" src="https://picsum.photos/180/280" alt="Link"> </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want to achieve. The issue with the answer you posted, is that it doesn't align at the end properly.